# Using try catch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html page with html element and js code. But if page doesn't have .chart I have js error in console.

So I  use try - catch. But it seems it isn't good.

```
try{
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        animate: 2000,
        barColor: '#333',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
} catch(err) {

}
```

So how can I modify my code?

Comment: `But it seems it isn't good.` why?

Comment: So what's the question? Do you want something to replace this? You could always check the result of `$('.chart')` to see if the length is greater than 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check if the element exists instead of using try..catch:

```
if ($('.chart').length > 0) {
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        animate: 2000,
        barColor: '#333',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check `.chart` length before call plugins. You can add `else` for  other condition. Don't use try catch for this purpose.

```js
if ($('.chart').length >0 ) 
{
$('.chart').easyPieChart({
        animate: 2000,
        barColor: '#333',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: At least if you use a snippet, include jQuery to avoid errors.

Comment: @Mouser Thanks for suggestion. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

A `try catch` is overpowered for this test:

```
if ($('.chart').length > 0 && $('.chart').easyPieChart) //this will test if the chart element is present and easyPieChart is available as a method.
{
  $('.chart').easyPieChart({
      animate: 2000,
      barColor: '#333',
      easing: 'easeOutBounce',
      onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
          $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
      }
  });

}
```

You basically want to test if an object is available. This is called feature detection and a simple if-else will suffice.

This should check if the method exists, if not you can use the else to do something. If the method doesn't exist it will return `undefined`.

The other methods suggested here use the inner workings of *jQuery*. When the jQuery function `$` is called with a selector and it isn't found the length property will be `0`. Indicating that no element was found. Since the element isn't there, the method doesn't exist either.

Comment: As far as I know, `$('.chart').easyPieChart` will always be true.

Comment: I can see two cases here. When the plugin is installed that could be true, when not installed this will return `undefined`. @SalmanA, still a good call, updated it.

Comment: OP claims that the page throws error when `.chart` element is missing so (although not explicitly mentioned) same works if the element is there.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. If the chart element doesn't exist in the DOM, an error will be thrown by jQuery. Catch it and print it to console to see the error. It may be a different error that has nothing to do with jQuery. Still, you should print it to console to see it or use Developer tools to check the err variable.

```
try{
    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
        animate: 2000,
        barColor: '#333',
        easing: 'easeOutBounce',
        onStep: function (from, to, percent) {
            $(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
} catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```

Also, try to make sure your DOM is fully loaded before you make the jQuery call i.e use a ready function. Otherwise the chart element may not exist when you run the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```